# i want to know the simplest easiet code of mail using php

Tags: php

i want to know the simplest easiet code of mail using php

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear but here is the simplest use of the `mail` function:

```
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

[See the docs for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

**Note:**

There are issues with using `mail` function:

- Email might be treated as spam
- The `SMTP` socket is issued for each mail
- Can not be used for bulk-emailing
- Unreliable use of new line character across plateforms

**Better Alternatives:**

You should when you can use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/)

Or:

[The SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 mail('bill@gmail.com', 'subject', 'Whazup');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

From [the php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).